# Python: Writing on a plain text file a really long list of consecutive numbers

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a really long list of consecutive numbers starting from 0 and finishing in like 10,000,000,000 or more and write it to a plain text file. What I currently have uses all the RAM (12 GB) and makes my computer to reboot.

```
i = 0
password = []

file = open("pass.txt", "a")
for i in range (10000):
    password.append("%016d" % (i,))

for elem in password:
    file.write(str(elem) + '\n')

file.close
print("Finished")
```

Comment: Side-note: You should really use `with` statements with files; on top of being exception safe and predictable (they always close when control flow exits the block by any means), it also avoids the need to remember to `close` at all (in this case, you didn't actually `close` even though you remembered to, because you didn't call `file.close`, you just loaded it and ignored it by omitting the parens, you wanted `file.close()`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't store the values in a `list`, just write them directly:

```
# Use with statement to automatically close file properly, even on exception
# as soon as block finishes
with open("pass.txt", "a") as file:
    for i in range(10000):
        file.write("%016d\n" % i)
print("Finished")
```

That will buffer the `write`s until the buffer fills, then flush it, so you'll write as you go, with fixed memory overhead.

Note: At the cost of perhaps being a bit overly concise, you could one-line the writing, pushing all the work to the C layer (on the CPython reference interpreter), by replacing the loop with:

```
    file.writelines(map("%016d\n".__mod__, range(10000)))

    # Or using format, which looks less hacky by avoiding manual use of operator overloads:
    file.writelines(map("{:016d}\n".format, range(10000)))
```

It's a microoptimization (the file I/O is almost certainly more expensive than what you're doing in Python), but I thought I'd point it out for completeness.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I'll be using the first aproach for more readability, but anyway good to know!